# php exclude last word with dot and get the first part

Tags: php

I want to fetch the image name from the string.

```
$pattern = "http://www.aaa.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/images1.jpg";
```

The output needed is `images1`

I tried using explode with end function but that just returns the last word i.e jpg. I am unable to find the reverse of end function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have different extensions you can use regex

```
preg_match('/.*\/([^.]+)\.[^.]+/', $pattern, $match);
$fname = $match[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) for filenames in paths, and use the second parameter to eliminate the extension.

```
echo basename($pattern, '.jpg'); // prints "images1"
```

See [DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XkIGp3).

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$pattern = "http://www.aaa.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/images1.jpg";
echo basename($pattern,'.jpg');
```

if you have different extensions, you can use `basename($pattern);` without suffix and then filter the extension later on

http://php.net/manual/de/function.basename.php makes for an interesting read if you need more information and some examples of use